# php setlocale works under cli mode but not web mode

Tags: php, setlocale

```
<?php
    echo(setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US"));
?>
```

The code above outputs en_US under cli mode, but false under web mode with apache2 in the same server.Why the method works correctly under cli mode but not web mode?

Comment: What OS are you using? Is apache running in threaded mode?

Comment: The server's OS is Debian 2.6.32. If threaded mode means prefork or work mode,I tried to execute 'aptitude search apache2-mpm-' and '/usr/sbin/apache -l' and both shown that mpm module is not intalled,I've also read apache config file,but there were not a word about mpm or worker or prefork.How can I check if apache is running multiprocess or multithread?

Comment: run: `if [ \`apache2 -l | grep prefork.c\` != "" ] ; then  echo "not threaded" ; else echo "threaded" ; fi` . I'm asking this because in threaded mode the locale is shared between several worker threads. Means, it will have side effects on ALL threads when changing the locale from inside of just one thread during runtime.

Comment: What is the output of `locale -a`?

Comment: "locale -a" in command line and via php "system('locale -a')" both output
"C POSIX en_US en_US.iso88591 ja_JP ja_JP.eucjp ja_JP.ujis ja_JP.utf8 japanese japanese.euc"

Comment: What if you try it using`POSIX` ?

Comment: echo(setlocale(LC_ALL, "POSIX")); outputs POSIX, both cli and web

Comment: Then it is definitely the issue that apache cannot find the en_US locale. can you `su -l www-data` (as root) and try the cli script again?

Comment: I've tried "sudo -u www-data php XXXXX.php",the result was en_US.